# Change rows in a df with rows from another one by a condition R

Tags: r, dataframe, rows

I'd like to know how to change a whole part of a df with rows from another one .

Here the two dataframes:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), y = c("a", "b", "c", "d", 'e', "f"), z = c("YES", "YES", "YES", "YES", "NO", "NO"))

df2 <- data.frame(x = c(8,9), y = c("l", "g"), z = c("YES","YES"))
```

I want to replace the "YES" rows of df1 with the ones from df2 by 'z' column.

```
x y   z
8 l YES
9 g YES
5 e  NO
6 f  NO
```

How I can do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify how you want to "change rows"? You have 4 rows with "YES" in column `z` in `df1` and replaced with 2 rows with "YES" in `df2`...do you replace in order of `df2` starting with row 1 in `df2`? If there are less rows with "YES" in `df2` do you just remove the extra rows in `df1`?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to replace in order of df2 starting with row 1 in df2 and yes, if there are extra rows in df1 just remove them.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to bind the "NO" rows of `df1` with `df2` ?

```
rbind(df2, df1[df1$z == "NO", ])

#  x y   z
#1 8 l YES
#2 9 g YES
#5 5 e  NO
#6 6 f  NO
```

Using `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)

df2 %>% bind_rows(df1 %>% filter(z == "NO"))
```

Comment: this is a simple example, my real case is a more complexed and I prefer to change rows in df1 and not to bind them in df2

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not entirely sure about this, and there are a number of assumptions - but thought this may be helpful.

You can quickly make a counter in `df1` for those with "YES" (using `cumsum`). You can create a logical vector `ind` to indicate which rows are "YES" in `df1` where the counter is less than the number of rows in `df2` (assumes all `df2` rows would be used). This addresses the mismatch between number of rows to replace in `df1`, and number of replacement rows in `df2`.

```
ind <- df1$z == "YES" & cumsum(df1$z == "YES") <= nrow(df2)
```

Then, to replace the rows marked for replacement, use:

```
df1[ind,] <- df2
```

Finally, remove rows with "YES" in `df1` that did not get replaced. This is the same as keeping those that were replaced or had "NO" for column `z`:

```
df1[ind | df1$z == "NO", ]
```

**Output**

```
  x y   z
1 8 l YES
2 9 g YES
5 5 e  NO
6 6 f  NO
```